# Can't read Root.plist with NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c

I've a problem. I have the file root.plist with many preferences but, when I use:

```
NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults
```

to read it, nothing happened. Why? Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would it read that file? User defaults aren't stored in a plist in your application bundle. If that file contains "first-run" preferences to set for all users you will need to read from the file yourself and copy the values to defaults using the standard methods.